# Douglas-Peucker line simplification algorithm time complexity

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, recurrence, proof

I am analyzing the time complexity of the [Douglas-Peucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) line simplification algorithm. Reading online I've found that it has a worst-case running time of `O(n^2)` where `n` is the number of points on the line. However, I haven't been able to provide complete proof. Here is the pseudo-code I am working with:

[image: pseudo-code]

Here is my analysis:

**Line 1:** `O(1)`

**Line 2:** We can say that it goes through all points in the polyline formed by the first point and the last point in `PL` and return the point with the maximum distance to the straight line between the mentioned points. We can safely say this is `O(n)`

**Lines 4-6:** If we are here we are doing two recursive calls. **The number of elements used in each call could be different (not always in half). Depends on the point found in Line 2**. Leaving implementation details aside, we can say that splitting is `O(1)`. Also, we have a `JOIN` operation which would take `O(n)` to join both lists.

**Line 8:** This is also a `JOIN` operation but this only takes `O(1)`.

After looking at these steps I think we have the following recurrence relation:

`T(n) = T(index + 1) + T(n - index) + 2n` where `index in [1, ..., n-1]`

Am I right? If so, how could I prove this is `O(n^2)`? Master Theorem?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: The worst case is when you always have `index=1` , so `T(n) = O(n) + T(n-1)`

Comment: Sorry @MattTimmermans, I made a mistake writing the recurrence, I meant `T(n) = T(index+1) + T(n-index) + 2n`.

Comment: Maybe, but I didn't make a mistake :)

Comment: @MattTimmermans, Ok, So following your comment, I get `T(n) = T(2) + T(n-1) + O(n)` Right? I can state that `T(2) = O(1)` (Line 8). And then, solving `T(n) = T(n-1) + O(n)` will yield `O(n^2)` right?

Comment: Yes, that's right